# SQL Server: how to declare and set variable in dynamic procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, declare

I would like to declare and set a variable as part of a dynamic procedure.

I am new to this so the following is just to indicate what I am trying to achieve. 
Can someone show me how to write this correctly (just regarding these lines) ?

```
@searchMain nvarchar(100) = '',
@searchInput nvarchar(256) = ''

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN   

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @searchDate datetime

CASE WHEN @searchMain = 'col1' THEN SET @searchDate = @searchInput ELSE SET @searchDate = '' END

SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP 100
-- ...
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, Mike.

Comment: your question looks like incomplete.Can you try to put the correct statements that you have and tell us what you are trying to achieve.?

Comment: I am assuming that the CASE line is not correct so I would like to know how to write this correctly

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?

Comment: Yes, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
CASE WHEN @searchMain = 'col1' THEN SET @searchDate = @searchInput ELSE SET @searchDate = '' END
```

To this:

```
SET @searchDate = CASE WHEN @searchMain = 'col1' THEN @searchInput ELSE '' END
```